# How to fix "Process exited before completing request"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm am trying to create thumbnail image creation when image upload into S3 bucket. I have created lambda function and dependent files. I have upload the files in function code of lambda. Finally i am trying to test, getting error.

**{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: cf395d5f-d8ad-41c3-977e-3ab3407037c0 Process exited before completing request"
}**

I have followed below link for reference
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Comment: You need to provide your lambda code.

Comment: Did the function timeout before it completed? You can try increasing the `Timeout` value.

Comment: code is available in this link.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Comment: Timeout is not problem, have some bucket configuration.